# Transaction Response "responseCode" Field

Tags: transactions, authorize.net

In the Authorize.NET Documentation, the payment transaction response has the field `responseCode`. According to documentation, the possible values are:

1. Approved
2. Declined
3. Error
4. Held for Review

What are the possible reasons for 2, 3, and 4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Declined

Declines are issued by the credit card issuing bank and can be for any reason they choose to decline a payment. The most common reasons are:

1. User does not have sufficient funds in their account
2. Card is not valid or does not exist
3. The bank suspects a potentially fraudulent transaction

> Error

This can be due to any number of reasons. The error could occur at the gateway, processor, or the card issuing bank.

> Held for Review

This can occur if you are using the Advanced Fraud Detection Suite (AFDS). If you do not use this feature, this status will not occur.